# Windows 10 doesnt display desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10

After months i finally decided to install windows 10 on my laptop.
After installing it looked like the whole laptop wouldnt work anymore but after restaring like ten times i heard the startup sound and my cursor appeared.

Now to the problem, the only thing i see on my screen is the cursor. I do not see the desktop. After pressing some hotkeys i found out that the screens that apear using hotkeys like opening the task manager works.

So my question is, is there a known fix to see my desktop again.

Comment: It sounds like you should boot into Safe Mode.  You can accomplish this by forcing Windows to fail to load 3 times.  This will automatically bring you into the Advanced Startup menu.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but even that screen isnt visable most of the time. It takes 10 tries to get to the login screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running explorer.exe as a new task via Task Manager. If desktop becomes visible you can add explorer.exe to start-up programs (again via Task Manager) and force start desktop at each boot even if it decides to play hide and seek again.

Comment: Intresting, i've tried what you said but as soon as i start the task it shows the desktop(ad expected) but instantly it disapears.

Comment: Does your start screen work when you press Windows button from keyboard? If so can you check if start -> settings -> system -> tablet mode  is set to automatic?

Comment: No that doesnt work

Comment: Do you know the process name of the settings?

Comment: It is a trusted store app which means you probably can't run it from task manager.

Comment: But i can from cmd right?

Comment: Can you try running eventvwr.msc (Event viewer) and see if any there is any error log created after you start explorer.exe?

Comment: I will try and ill let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31054/discussion-between-mustafa-aktas-and-collin-koornstra).